# How do I get Html Table to respect margins when its width is set to 100%?

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get an Html Table to fill the width of a container, and respect margins without overflowing.

This sample (see https://jsfiddle.net/v6o12u9o/) sets a table's width to 100%, but because of the margin, the table overflows its parent's borders. How do I fix this?

Html:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red; margin:10px;">
<table border=1>
    <tr>
        <td>
            First cell.
        </td>
        <td>
            Second cell.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Css:

```
table {
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
    width:100%;
}

td {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Some other things I've tried:

- Setting margin-right to 40px. Margin-right is ignored.
- Setting padding-right instead. This makes the cells smaller, but the table stays at 100% width.
- Setting table's display to "block". This makes the table the correct size, but then cells are too small (I tried setting "block" on the cells, no luck)

Comment: Is this what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/v6o12u9o/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want table to be 100% you can do this and compensate for the margins on left and right by moving that to padding on the parent:

CSS:

```
.tableElement {
    margin: 20px auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
}

.tableCell {
    width: 50%;
}

.tableWrapper {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tableWrapper">
    <table class="tableElement" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableCell">First cell.</td>
            <td>Second cell.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v6o12u9o/5/

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I think you want: https://jsfiddle.net/v6o12u9o/4/

```
//uses padding instead of margin
div {
 border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
padding: 20px;
width:100%;

}

tr {
background-color: yellow;

}

td {
 width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Adding padding to the table was the best solution for me, since I didn't have to add any additional markup (a wrapper div).

Answer (score 1):

Loads of answers but I thought I would put my solution also. I changed the CSS to that instead of the table having a margin, the div wrapper had padding instead and the table row was set to 100%.

```
div {
    padding: 10px;    
}
table {
    background-color: yellow;
    width:100%;
}
tr {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `width: 100%` and `margin: 20px` the child will overflow.
Try setting the margin on only top and bottom and limiting the `width` to 90%. It will accomplish the same thing in your example.

Because `margin-left` and `margin-right` are set to `auto`, it will also center inside the parent.

```
    table {
      margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
      background-color: yellow;
      width: 90%;
    }
```

Comment: That works ok, but I think I prefer the padding suggestions from some of the other answers, I can be a bit more precise then with the pixel amounts. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: After seeing the other answers, i agree with your assesment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, if you want it wider you can change the width in the table style. I hope this is what your looking for.

```
table {
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    background-color: yellow;
    width:95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to do this is display mode for that element. that forces the elements to be more fluid.

```
.table {
  display:block;
  margin:20px auto;
}
```

setting the tables display to block will make it fill the space it has available and the rest you can do with css for colour and style.

Comment: When I do that the cells don't fill the entire table anymore. Strange.